# Change Layout of Joomla article list with custom php

Tags: php, joomla

Having spent a few days banging my head against a brick wall with this I need some help. I basically want to change the code here:

```
<div class="itemList">

        <?php if(isset($this->leading) && count($this->leading)): ?>
        <!-- Leading items -->
        <div id="itemListLeading">
            <?php foreach($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>

            <?php
            // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
            if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_leading_columns'))==0) || count($this->leading)<$this->params->get('num_leading_columns') )
                $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
            else
                $lastContainer='';
            ?>

            <div class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>"<?php echo (count($this->leading)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$this->params->get('num_leading_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>>
                <?php
                    // Load category_item.php by default
                    $this->item=$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_leading_columns'))==0): ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(isset($this->primary) && count($this->primary)): ?>
        <!-- Primary items -->
        <div id="itemListPrimary">
            <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): ?>

            <?php
            // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
            if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_primary_columns'))==0) || count($this->primary)<$this->params->get('num_primary_columns') )
                $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
            else
                $lastContainer='';
            ?>

            <div class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>"<?php echo (count($this->primary)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$this->params->get('num_primary_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>>
                <?php
                    // Load category_item.php by default
                    $this->item=$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_primary_columns'))==0): ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(isset($this->secondary) && count($this->secondary)): ?>
        <!-- Secondary items -->
        <div id="itemListSecondary">
            <?php foreach($this->secondary as $key=>$item): ?>

            <?php
            // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
            if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_secondary_columns'))==0) || count($this->secondary)<$this->params->get('num_secondary_columns') )
                $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
            else
                $lastContainer='';
            ?>

            <div class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>"<?php echo (count($this->secondary)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$this->params->get('num_secondary_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>>
                <?php
                    // Load category_item.php by default
                    $this->item=$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_secondary_columns'))==0): ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(isset($this->links) && count($this->links)): ?>
        <!-- Link items -->
        <div id="itemListLinks">
            <h4><?php echo JText::_('K2_MORE'); ?></h4>
            <?php foreach($this->links as $key=>$item): ?>

            <?php
            // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
            if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_links_columns'))==0) || count($this->links)<$this->params->get('num_links_columns') )
                $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
            else
                $lastContainer='';
            ?>

            <div class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>"<?php echo (count($this->links)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$this->params->get('num_links_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>>
                <?php
                    // Load category_item_links.php by default
                    $this->item=$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item_links');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_links_columns'))==0): ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

So that 'leading' displays a certain number of articles, then 'primary' displays the next two, 'secondary' the next four and so on.

Any help on how to do that would be great

Comment: Which file does the code you provided come from? and are you using standard Joomla articles or K2?

Comment: It comes from the category.php file in the K2 directory, this is for the K2 category layout. Really cant work it out!

Answer (score 1):

The file is located here:

> /layouts/joomla/content/category_default.php

To override it place a copy here:

> [YOUR_TEMPLATE]/html/layouts/joomla/content/

You can read more about Joomla layouts here:

[Sharing layouts across views or extensions with JLayout](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3ASharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout)